# Cannot set UIPickerView dataSource / delegate programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that I've placed on my story board and created a reference to the picker in my controller. In my controller, I would like to set the delegate programmatically. Here is what I've tried:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let textPickerDelegate = TextPickerdDelegate(text1: text1, text2: text2, picker: picker)

        text1.delegate = textPickerDelegate
        text2.delegate = textPickerDelegate

        picker.delegate = textPickerDelegate
        picker.dataSource = textPickerDelegate
        picker.hidden = true
    }
}
```

The code for the delegate looks like this:

```
class TextPickerDelegate: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    static let TEXT_1_DATA: Array<Array<String>> = {
        let text1Data: Array<Array<String>> = [[], ["a", "b"]]
        for i in 1...100 {
            var text1 = text1Data[0] as Array<String>
            text1.append(String(i))
        }
        return text1Data
    }()

    static let TEXT_2_DATA: Array<Array<String>> = {
        let text2Data: Array<Array<String>> = [[], ["c", "d"]]
        for i in 1...100 {
            var text2 = text2Data[0] as Array<String>
            text2.append(String(i))
        }
        return text2Data
    }()

    let text1: UITextField
    let text2: UITextField
    let picker: UIPickerView

    var pickerData: Array<Array<String>> = TextPickerDelegate.TEXT_1_DATA

    init(text1: UITextField, text2: UITextField, picker: UIPickerView) {
        self.text1 = text1
        self.text2 = text2
        self.picker = picker
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return pickerData[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        // Select the row
        picker.hidden = true;
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if (textField == text1) {
            pickerData = TextPickerDelegate.TEXT_1_DATA
        } else if (textField == text2) {
            pickerData = TextPickerDelegate.TEXT_2_DATA
        }

        picker.hidden = false
        return false
    }
}
```

As soon as I try to render the view containing the picker, I get the following error:

```
2015-08-20 20:19:14.840 MyApp[13642:645025] -[_UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe072d64ba0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textPickerDelegate` is local to `viewDidLoad`. Try moving the declaration one level up, like the IBOutlets.

I think you also have a potential problem with your TEXT_?_DATA, see my added comment inside:

```
static let TEXT_1_DATA: Array<Array<String>> = {
        let text1Data: Array<Array<String>> = [[], ["a", "b"]]
        for i in 1...100 {
            var text1 = text1Data[0] as Array<String> // <-- this creates a copy, not a reference
            text1.append(String(i)) // <-- this appends to the copy, leaving the original intact
        }
        return text1Data
    }()
```

As a quick alternative you can try this:

```
let text1Data = [(1...100).map { String($0) }, ["a", "b"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip using the range. When I try to move the delegate out of the method, I get an error that says `MyController has no field text1`.

Comment: Right. You need to do something like this: ` var textPickerDelegate: TextPickerdDelegate! = nil` and in the viewDidLoad `textPickerDelegate = TextPickerdDelegate(text1: text1, text2: text2, picker: picker)
`

Comment: I don't see how this could be the issue. `TextPickerDelegate` gets allocated on the heap and I should be able to pass references to it around. But somehow it did solve the issue...

Comment: Gets allocated on the heap and removed from it when it goes out of scope.  The delegate is weak - `weak var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate?`, so it won't keep it alive... By changing the scope you made it live longer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the delegate to your UIViewController like so

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
```

This is assuming that you want to have a standard UIPickerView

Comment: I don't want the ViewController to be the delegate though. In my code you can see I try to set the delegate explicitly.

Comment: My bad. Sorry, I can't help you with that.